# Concept to create thread wide/class wide object

Tags: java, conceptual

I'm searching for a **concept** to forward an object to subobjects.

Example: 
I would like to create log files for several main Objects, that include sub objects (imagine a REST server that would log every single connection by ID).

Creating one big log file is simple ( redirect System.out.println, I already encapsulated that)
Example code:

```
    class SubElementA{
    public SubElementA(){
        Debugger.debug("I am called, too");
    }

}
```

Application.java

```
package com.dev4ag;

class Application{
private ElementA elA;
private String prefix;
public Application(String name){
    this.elA = new ElementA();
    this.prefix = name;
}

public void countUp(){
    Debugger.debug(this.prefix+": I will now count up");
    this.elA.doSomeStuff();
}

}
```

ElementA.java

```
package com.dev4ag;

class ElementA{
    private int counter;
    private SubElementA subElementA;
    public void doSomeStuff(){
        counter++;
        Debugger.debug("Counter is: "+counter);
    }

    //Constructor
    public ElementA(){
        subElementA = new SubElementA();
        this.counter = 0;
    };
}
```

SubElementA.java

```
package com.dev4ag;

class SubElementA{
    public SubElementA(){
        Debugger.debug("I am called, too");
    }

}
```

Debugger.java

```
package com.dev4ag;
public class Debugger {
    public static void debug(String output){
        //Just imagine we would write to a file here ;)
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

(it was more easy to write system.out.println than to create a file, just imagine, Debugger.debug would write to a file).

Now I am thinking about a solution to create one Debug output target for each App. I could definitely change debug to not being static and create a debug object within Application.

But is there any way to use this object in the sub classes without forwarding the debug object either through Constructor or setter function, which would mean to have to add an object for the debugger to each class?

What would be the most beautiful solution for that?

Comment: If you just need to correlate the debug messages by thread, consider including thread name in each print (`Thread.currentThread().getName()` ). If you need to maintain a state specific to a thread, have a look at `ThreadLocal` variables - perhaps the debugger can set a `ThreadLocal` at the entry point of your code (where the request is first handled), and use it in subsequent invocations.

Comment: Have you checked **[logback](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html)** it may have all you need such as writing to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this solution might decrease performance a lot and it is pretty dirty way, but some loggers include such data.

But you can use `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` to get stacktrace like in error and get class and method from where your method was called.

If you are using java9+ then you should probably use StackWalker API instead, especially that it have nice filters and other useful features.
So then you could guess app by class/method names on the stack.